# Issues with WinForms Form.Controls.Add

Tags: c#, winforms

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express
Windows Forms C#

---

Horay, more issues with ControlCollections and Form.Controls.Add()!

```
        private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        data.mainForm_startControls = this.Controls;
        data.wizard_tabs = new Wizard_Tabs().Controls[0];
        debug(1);
        this.Controls.Clear();
        debug(2);
     >  this.Controls.Add(data.mainForm_startControls[3]);
        debug(3);
        }
```

Why does the highlighted (with a >) line act as a "return;" statement in this snippet?

If it's executed, debug(3); doesn't run. I don't have the wisdom to solve this.

The line itself doesn't even execute. Removing it fixes all of it, so it's the problem!

If you were wondering what data. stands for:

```
namespace Project_Management_Wizard {
public class dataStorage {
    public System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection mainForm_startControls;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Control wizard_tabs;

    }
}


public dataStorage data = new dataStorage();
```

---

Something I didn't quite figure out at start is that the ControlCollection is just an array of references to the actual Controls. Copying it only makes a copy of references. I thought ControlCollection holds the actual elements, so I can copy the elements by copying the ControlCollection. Copying the ControlCollection doesn't copy any collections, so editing the collections it points to gives errors.

Comment: That line raises an exception which is then swallowed at some point higher on the stack?

Comment: Is an exception thrown?  Are you sure the debugger is attached to the correct version of the code?  There's nothing here that would cause it to return from the function scope.

Comment: Apparently, +  $exception {"Index 0 is out of range.\r\nParameter name: index"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}. I'm pretty sure Index 0 isn't out of range. Does this mean my assignment data.mainForm_startControls = this.Controls; failed?

Comment: @AlucardF0X: It means that assignment didn't do what you think.  It didn't record a copy of the current state of the collection, it just made a reference (`ControlCollection` is a reference type).  When you change the collection via one reference, all references are affected because there was only one collection to begin with.

Comment: How do I control when C# makes a reference and when it creates a copy? It seems that C# does this at random, where it's most inconvenient for me.

Comment: @AlucardF0X you don't control it and it isn't random.  Objects are **always** assigned by reference.  You just have to work with it more to understand how it behaves.

Answer (score 4):

I think the line you selected throws an exception and therefore the next line will not execute.

The reason for an exception is the fact, that data.mainForm_startControls[3] doesnt exist, because the collection is empty. You cleared it with this.Controls.Clear(). Because this.Controls and data.mainForm_startControls are the same pointers, the Clear method clears also data.mainForm_startControls.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like that line is throwing an exception. Try placing a try/catch block around it, then place a breakpoint in the catch and see if it is in fact throwing.

Things to check for:

- Is `mainForm_startControls` instantiated?
- Does `mainForm_startControls` actually have 4 elements in it, so that `mainForm_startControls[3]` will return a value?

Comment: Of course it doesn't have 4 elements, the previous line cleared the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is dealing with assignment by reference, when you think you are creating a copy.

When you assign `data.mainForm_startControls = this.Controls;` you are assigning a reference to `this.Controls` to `data.mainForm_startControls`.  This is standard with dealing with any reference type in C#.  You aren't copying the collection, you are just assigning it to a 2nd variable.

If you modify `this.Controls`, virtually any change will be reflected in `data.mainForm_startControls`.  In fact, the only change I can think of at the moment that would not impact `data.mainForm_startControls` is if you actually created a brand new object and assigned it to `this.Controls`.

So when you call `this.Controls.Clear()`, you are clearing the ControlCollection object and since `data.mainForm_startControls` references the same object, you are clearing it as well.

What you need to do instead is assign the individual elements to a new collection rather than assigning the entire collection.

First, I'd suggest changing `ControlCollection` in dataStorage to a more modern collection, such as `List<T>`.  Dealing with Generic collection classes in .NET is a lot easier since everything is strongly typed.

```
public class dataStorage {
    public List<Control> mainForm_startControls = new List<Control>()
    public System.Windows.Forms.Control wizard_tabs;

}
```

Then you can replace `data.mainForm_startControls = this.Controls;` with a foreach loop to copy the individual controls:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
    data.mainForm_startControls.Add(item);
}
```

So this way you have a brand new collection that will hold references to each of the controls, and it won't get cleared when you call `this.Controls.Clear()`